# how to merge cells in ireport 4.5.0

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using iReport 4.5.0, in that I used one table with 5 column and 5 rows. Now in 3rd row I want to combine cell number 2 and 3. Means in 3rd row there will be 4 cols.

Comment: Can you post image to illustrate your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Are you combining the contents of two fields? You could start a new text field and edit the expression to read:

$F{field1} + " " + $F{field2}